# Python if statement getting: 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Condition worked independently, but adding as part of an `if`, is getting truth ambiguous:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,5), columns=list('ABCDE'))
df1
# df1.loc[(df1.D > 1.25) | (df1.D < -0.25)] # work
# df1.loc[:,'D'] > 0.1 # work
if df1.loc[:,'D'] > 0.1:
    print(df1['A'] * df1['B'])
```

reference:
[Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: that is what I put as reference too but it does not answer the question

Answer (score 1):

`df.loc[:,'D'] > 0.1` gives you a vector of true and false values:

```
Out[1]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: D, dtype: bool
```

It's not sure how to convert a vector of true and false into a single value. You could assume all: `if (df1.loc[:,'D'] > 0.1).all():`, any: `if (df1.loc[:,'D'] > 0.1).any():`, or iterate through:

```
for item in (df1.loc[:,'D'] > 0.1):
    if item:
        print('something')
```

Without knowing more about what you're trying to do python and I are just guessing.

So looking at your edit, I think you're trying to multiply A and B and take the values when `D > 0.1`, which is easy:

`(df1['A'] * df1['B'])[(df1.loc[:,'D'] > 0.1)]`

```
1   -0.590544
3   -0.371079
8   -0.704530
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have updated the question. overall I wanted to do multiplication of resulting df's two columns

Comment: Think I've got what you're trying to do now

Comment: this thing work independent but not with if..if (df1.loc[:,'D'] > 0.1):
    df2 = df1['A'] * df['B']
    print(df2)

Comment: do you want it to print if _all_ of them are > 0.1, if _any_ of them are > 0.1, or only the ones where D > 0.1?

Comment: only the ones which are D > 0.1

Comment: you can do `print((df1['A'] * df1['B'])[(df1.loc[:,'D'] > 0.1)])`; if you want to use an if statement iterate through: `[print(df1.loc[i, 'A'] * df1.loc[i, 'B']) for i, item in enumerate(df1.loc[:, 'D']) if item > 0.1]`